# Error parsing emails using Python's email module when the encoding is in shift_jis

Tags: python, parsing, email, shift-jis

I am getting an error that says "UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: illegal multibyte sequence" when I try to use my email parser to decode a shift_jis encoded email and convert it to unicode. The code and email can be found below:

```
import email.header
import base64
import sys
import email

def getrawemail():
    line = ' '
    raw_email = ''
    while line:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        raw_email += line
    return raw_email

def getheader(subject, charsets):
    for i in charsets:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            encoding = i
            break
    if subject[-2] == "?=":
        encoded = subject[5 + len(encoding):len(subject) - 2]
    else:
        encoded = subject[5 + len(encoding):]
    return (encoding, encoded)

def decodeheader((encoding, encoded)):
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    decoded = unicode(decoded, encoding)
    return decoded

raw_email = getrawemail()
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
subject = decodeheader(getheader(msg["Subject"], msg.get_charsets()))
print subject
```

Email: http://pastebin.com/L4jAkm5R

I have read on another Stack Overflow question that this may be related to a difference between how Unicode and shift_jis are encoded (they referenced [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170559) Microsoft Knowledge Base article). If anyone knows what in my code could be causing it to not work, or if this is even reasonably fixable, I would very much appreciate finding out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this string:

```
In [124]: msg['Subject']
Out[124]: '=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCNS5KfSRLJEgkRiRiQmdAWiRKJCpDTiRpJDskLCQiJGo'
```

`=?ISO-2022-JP?B?` means the string is ISO-2022-JP encoded, then base64 encoded.

```
In [125]: msg['Subject'].lstrip('=?ISO-2022-JP?B?')
Out[125]: 'GyRCNS5KfSRLJEgkRiRiQmdAWiRKJCpDTiRpJDskLCQiJGo'
```

Unfortunately, trying to reverse that process results in an error:

```
In [126]: base64.b64decode(msg['Subject'].lstrip('=?ISO-2022-JP?B?'))
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

Reading this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419977/japanese-email-subject-encoding/492543#492543) lead me to try adding '?=' to the end of the string:

```
In [130]: print(base64.b64decode(msg['Subject'].lstrip('=?ISO-2022-JP?B?')+'?=').decode('ISO-2022-JP'))
貴方にとても大切なお知らせがあり
```

According to google translate, this may be translated as "You know there is a very important".

So it appears the subject line has been truncated.